# How to detect anomalies in float[] array samples with ML.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I'm collecting FFT sample data from a hardware device with a .NET Core application. The data structure is a float array of 4096 values per sample. Each of these values represents a small frequency band and its amplitude. These float arrays come in regularly as the live measurement continues.

For analysis I need to be able to train a model on data captured during a learning period. When the learning is done, new samples must be compared and evaluated. If the sample (FFT frequency spectrum) looks similar to what's been observed during training, the result is good. If it looks considerably different, the result is bad and this should be indicated by an existing UI.

I only need that training and classification part. I've already read the ML.NET website and guess I need to anomaly detection feature of ML.NET. It can be trained with good data only and should detect bad data automatically without having seen it in advance. Unfortunately, all examples I could find only have samples of a single number. None try to use a whole number array as data. So I have no idea how to accomplish that. Is ML.NET even capable of this and is it a suitable tool for the task? I don't have the time of business competence to thoroughly study and understand the examples provided by the ML.NET website. I only have this float[4096] data set and would like to use this as first practical steps into ML.

Comment: Why are you getting bad floating point number?  You need to solve root cause not patch and throw away corrupted data.

Comment: Huh? This is an FFT module processing data from a vibration sensor. That sensor is *supposed to provide any* accurate measurement data, good and bad. If "bad" data is provided, it means that the monitored machine is not working properly. That needs to be fixed, yes, but first I have to measure and detect that. ML should help me detect that. That's what I'm asking for. So I have to tell apart the good from the bad data. All of them are 4096 float values in an array.

Comment: A float number is 32 bytes and not all combinations are valid.  So first we have to be in agreement what is bad data?  Is bad data corrupted float numbers or values that are not in range?  If you have corrupted float numbers than you are not transferring bytes properly between processes.

Comment: "Bad data" is a float array that contains vibration measurements of a defective machine. "Good data" is a float array that contains vibration measurements of a healthy machine. Both float arrays contain 4096 values in the range or 0 to 12. They're just distributed differently. And I cannot predict in which way because each machine is different. That's why observed good data needs to be learned/trained. Nothing is corrupted here, it's just the distinction/classification of good and bad.

Comment: I think this is a two step operation 1) You have a valid min/max frequency and min/max amplitude.  2) Within good data you may have noise that also make results bad.  So first step is easy to remove and doesn't need machine learning.  Second step you can use filter to make a band block filter to remove fundamental frequency.  Then use machine learning on results of filter.  The problem you are having is a signal to noise and attempting to do machine learning on a system with a good  signal to noise is a problem.

Comment: Okay, I can restrict on the frequency with the biggest amplitude and only compare its index (and maybe amplitude). That might work sufficiently well for now. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: You may want to ask question at Matlab site.  I'm not a DSP expert.  They can recommend a filter.  I think you want to create an ideal signal.  The subtract the good samples from the ideal and build model from the results of the subtraction.  Also take the signals that you analyze and subtract from ideal.  Not sure if ideal should be a synthesis signal or a combination of the good signals.

Comment: In the 1970's there is an Elton Join Live Concert in Central Park where a helicopter took videos of the concert and the blade noise got onto the sound track.  You can always tell the live version from the blade noise.  Years later when they release a new version sound engineers used DSP filters to remove the noise.  It was a selling point of the album but you could still hear the noise.  Other Engineers also attempted to remove noise.  A popular professor assignment was to develop DSP filters.  There are lots of white papers on web that you can find.  Maybe even a machine learning example.

Comment: Just to follow-up: Finding the most-occurring main frequency in all training samples and calculating the frequency shift of a live sample did the trick. I also added a comparison for the amplitude of the main frequency to detect other differences and a loss of the vibration (machine turned off).